# androidplot continuous sensor

Tags: android, dynamic, androidplot

need help with this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/androidplot&showsearch=true&showtabs=true&showpopout=true&hideforumtitle=true&hidesubject=true&showsearch=true&contenturl=http%3A%2F%2Fandroidplot.com%2Fforum%2F#!topic/androidplot/pD9K3P8wMhg

Hi,

I'm using 0.6 version of the library and i wanted know how to plot sensor data continuously rather than when i get updates from the sensor?

like so
[image]

rather than

[image]

Comment: There is a tutorial you can follow here: http://androidplot.com/docs/dynamically-plotting-sensor-data/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is sensors sample in api demos sample sdk app i hope it would help you.

Comment: here a link to the source of that sample:

https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot/src/27b81dcf278f79e15f21658dbd0381aa9e9a1153/Examples/DemoApp/src/com/androidplot/demos/OrientationSensorExampleActivity.java?at=master